# Comprobar datos en constructor php

Tags: php, poo, diseño-de-clases

Hola buenos dias y gracias de antemano.
Tengo la siguiente clase en php

```
class Electrodomestico
{
    protected $precio_base;
    protected $color='blanco';
    protected $consumo_energetico;
    protected $peso;
}
```

Y quiero comprobar dentro del constructor que **consumo_energetico** y que **color** sean datos correctos. Para ello tengo las siguientes funciones

```
public function comprobarConsumo($letra)
    {
        if (gettype($letra) == 'string') {
            if (
                strtoupper($letra) == 'A' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'B' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'C' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'D' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'E' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'F'
            ) {
                return $letra;
                $this->consumo_energetico = $letra;
            } else {
                return $letra;
                $this->consumo_energetico = 'F';
            }
        } else {
            return $letra;
            $this->consumo_energetico = 'F';
        }
    }
    public function comprobarColor($c)
    {
        if (gettype($c) == 'string') {
            if (
                strtoupper($c) == 'BLANCO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'NEGRO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'ROJO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'AZUL' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'GRIS'
            ) {
                return $c;
                $this->color = $c;
            } else {
                return $c;
                $this->color = 'BLANCO';
            }
        } else {
            return $c;
            $this->color = 'BLANCO';
        }
    }
```

Mi problema surge al llamar a las funciones dentro del constructor, tengo la siguiente sintaxis, pero me devuelve **NULL**

```
function __construct(
        $colorElectrodo,
        $consumo_energeticoElectrodo,
        $pesoElectrodo = 5,
        $precio_baseElectrodo = 100
    ) {
        $this->precio_base = $precio_baseElectrodo;
        $this->color=$this->comprobarColor($colorElectrodo);
        $this->consumo_energetico=$this->comprobarConsumo($consumo_energeticoElectrodo);
        $this->peso = $pesoElectrodo;
    }
```

Mi única idea es sacar estos métodos fuera de la clase, pero no es lo más adecuado.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te devuelve null?

Comment: Tanto **comprobarColor($c)** como **comprobarConsumo($letra)**

Comment: En el caso de comprobarConsumo($letra) ¿seguro que le estás pasando una letra? Porque si no le pasas nada, tal y como está la función no te va a devolver nada (null).

Comment: te recomendaria que empezaras a mirar DDD, ya que esto lo puedes solucionar aplicando ValueObjects, que serian los que validarian la creacion de tu Electrodomestico.

Comment: En primer lugar tu ```__construct``` esta mal formado, ya que estas usando PHP 8, en tu ejemplo primero declaras ```protected $precio_base;```, y esto deberia ir en dentro de tu ```__construct```, ejemplo: ```class TuClase {  public function __construct( public float x = 0.0, public float $y = 0.0, ) {} }```, te dejo una referencia: https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución estaba en el acceso a los metodos y los datos que devolvian, los declaré estaticos y comprobé los valores que devolvian de la siguiente forma:

```
public static function comprobarConsumo($letra)
    {
        if (gettype($letra) == 'string') {
            if (
                strtoupper($letra) == 'A' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'B' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'C' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'D' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'E' ||
                strtoupper($letra) == 'F'
            ) {
                return $letra;
            } else {
                $letra = 'F';
                return $letra;
            }
        } else {
            $letra = 'F';
            return $letra;
        }
    }
    public static function comprobarColor($c)
    {
        if (gettype($c) == 'string') {
            if (
                strtoupper($c) == 'BLANCO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'NEGRO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'ROJO' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'AZUL' ||
                strtoupper($c) == 'GRIS'
            ) {
                return $c;
            } else {
                $c = 'BLANCO';
                return $c;
            }
        } else {
            $c = 'BLANCO';
            return $c;
        }
    }
```

Y a la hora de usarlas en el constructor lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
function __construct(
        $colorElectrodo,
        $consumo_energeticoElectrodo,
        $pesoElectrodo = 5,
        $precio_baseElectrodo = 100
    ) {
        $this->precio_base = $precio_baseElectrodo;
        $this->color = self::comprobarColor($colorElectrodo);
        $this->consumo_energetico = self::comprobarConsumo($consumo_energeticoElectrodo);
        $this->peso = $pesoElectrodo;
    }
```